# How to set the range until last row of a column in sheet using Google App Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am creating a formula where it will be effective until the last row of a particular column (for example last row of column B) in AppScript. I have attached the formula here. Can anyone help me with it

```
sheet.getRange("A2:A11").setFormula('=IF(ISBLANK(B2:B),"",(B2:B &"."&substitute(substitute(lower(C2:C),"jalan","jln")," ","")))');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var lastR = getLastDataRow(sheet,"A")
sheet.getRange("A2:A" + lastR).setFormula('=IF(ISBLANK(B2:B),"",(B2:B &"."&substitute(substitute(lower(C2:C),"jalan","jln")," ","")))');
```

and add this function

```
function getLastDataRow(sheet,col) {
// col in letter
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(col + lastRow);
  if (range.getValue() !== "") {
    return lastRow;
  } else {
    return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  }              
}
```